# Normalize Time Series - Scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, normalization

I have:

1. 3 wikipedia article access counts (weekly)  (A-B-C)
2. Ground truth data (weekly)
3. Total wikipedia english article traffic counts (weekly)

My purpose is, build a multiple linear regression with **3 wikipedia article access counts** and try to predict future **ground truth data**.

Before start to build multiple linear regression, I want to make some pre processing( normalization or scaling ) on my 3 wikipedia access count data.

My data format is like this.

```
    date     | A (x1)     | B (x2)  |  C (x3) | total_en     | ground truth(y)

 01/01/2008  |   5611     |   606   |    376  |  1467923911  | 3.13599886
 08/01/2008  |   8147     |   912   |    569  |  1627405409  | 2.53335614
 15/01/2008  |   9809     |   873   |    597  |  1744099880  | 2.91287713
 22/01/2008  |   12020    |   882   |    600  |  1804646235  | 3.44497102  
 ...         |    ...     |   ...   |    ...  |    ...       | ...
```

Without normalization I build my multiple linear regression like this.

> wiki3.shape = (150,3) // include A-B-C article with numpy array
>
> ground_truth = (150,1) // include ground truth data in numpy array

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(wiki3, ground_truth, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

**My question is for better results How can I normalize/scale my x1,x2,x3 and y data ?**

**Should I normalize each article with the total english article traffic or should I use another way ?**

**Is K-Fold cross validation sensible for time-series ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To scale your data, you can use `sklearn.preprocessing.scale`. If `date` is your `index`, it's as simple as `wiki3_scaled = scale(wiki3)` (if not, then `date` would also be scaled, which you likely don't want).

Normalizing with `total_en` is a modeling decision. If you have reason to believe `A / total_en` is a better feature than `A`, then go for it. Better yet, try both.

If you're trying to predict `ground truth` from same-day `A`, `B` and `C`, then it's not really a time-series problem and k-Fold cross-validation is certainly sensible. If you're trying to predict a future `ground truth` from today's `A`, `B`, `C`, `ground truth` and maybe the respective lagged variables, then I don't see why you can't cross-validate either; just be careful to set it up such that you train on history and cross-validate against the future.

You might get better answers on these modeling decisions on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), since StackOverFlow is more programming-focused.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have past data for A,B,C article and ground truth data. A,B,C article data comes earlier than ground truth data like 1 week.
So when I have got A,B,C article access count, I try to predict what will ground truth count is.  So do you think that k-fold cross validation is sensible now ?